# Javascript Then() Promise is not working Asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm trying to figure out how to make this Firestore Collection asynchronously. I currently have it in a recursive function because a for loop wasn't working either. I thought by using a recursive function it would give me more control for when I wanted to start the function over, but it's still not working. Please help. I know this would be something easy to solve for most people.

```js
const fakeIt = async () => {
    console.log("A");
    
    var itemsCreated = 1;
    items(0, itemsCreated);
    
    async function items(num, itemsCreated){
        if(num < itemsCreated){
            console.log("B");
            
            await db.collection('items').add({
                          active: true
            }).then(async (item) => {
                console.log("C");
                items(num + 1, itemsCreated)
            });
        }else{
            console.log("Done");
        }
    }
}
Array(2).fill(0).forEach(fakeIt);
```

The print out I'm getting is as follow:

```
A
B
A
B
C
Done
C
Done
```

I need the result of:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
Done
```

Comment: Should you be `await`ing `fakeIt`?

Comment: You have a typo in `aysnc function items(...`, it should be `async` not `aysnc`. Also, why are you using `then` if you're also using `await`?

Comment: You're also not passing anything to `fakeIt`, is the `Array.fill()` bit just to run it twice?

Comment: shouldn't use both await and then at the same time :)

Comment: @Noah - I think I need to await fakeIt. That may be the problem.

Comment: @Phix -  I fixed the typo. Also, I need to use then() because I need to get the "item.id" from Firestore.

Comment: @ZacAnger - Array.fill() is being used to run it twice.

Comment: The point of using async/await is to get out of using then().

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using a recursive function for the fakeIt loop. I got rid of all of the async-await and everything works perfectly. Thank to those that made the comments above.

```
function fakeIt(number, count) {

     if (number < count) {

          console.log("A");
    
          var itemsCreated = 1;
          items(0, itemsCreated);
    
          function items(num, itemsCreated){

               if(num < itemsCreated){
                    console.log("B");
            
                   db.collection('items').add({
                          active: true
                    }).then(async (item) => {
                         console.log("C");
                         items(num + 1, itemsCreated)
                    });
               }else{

                    fakeIt(number+1, count)
               }
       }else{

            console.log("Done");
       }
}
fakeIt(0, 2)
```